# i get an error in the imports and in the chrome-driver and web-driver

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testing

I tried to launch chrome browser on ecplise. I already added all JAR file which is required for the selenium webdriver. I add maven dependencies executed successfully. But when I tried the code of launching chrome browser it gives me different types of error everytime I click on run. I tried on diffrent different website to sortout this error.

I tried various types of jar files to add in maven dependencies, but that did not work then I cleaned up the Eclipse build project then added external jar files. When I executed it gave me an editor that was not the main type.

some changes in that it gives selection is not a main type.

I expect  the result like that I want to know about How to launch the Chrome browser and click on all buttons to click on that automatically and how to work automatically in that browser.

This is my all Jar Files below:

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\auto-service-annotations-1.1.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\byte-buddy-1.14.12.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\checker-qual-3.41.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\commons-exec-1.3.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\error_prone_annotations-2.23.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\failsafe-3.3.2.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\failureaccess-1.0.2.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\guava-33.0.0-jre.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\jsr305-3.0.2.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-api-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-api-events-1.35.0-alpha.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-context-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-exporter-logging-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-extension-incubator-1.35.0-alpha.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-common-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure-spi-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-logs-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-metrics-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-sdk-trace-1.35.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\opentelemetry-semconv-1.23.1-alpha.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-api-4.18.1.jar

C:\Software\selenium-chrome-driver-2.53.0.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-chrome-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-chromium-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-devtools-v120-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-devtools-v121-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-devtools-v122-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-devtools-v85-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-edge-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-firefox-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-http-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-ie-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-java-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-json-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-manager-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-os-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-remote-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-safari-driver-4.18.1.jar

C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\selenium-support-4.18.1.jar

This is my error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at OpenApplication.main(OpenApplication.java:12)
```

This is my  code below:

```
package JavaPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class OpenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        //WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        // 1. Setting the property of chrome browser and passing ChromeDriver path
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Software\\chromedriver-win64.exe");

        // 2.  Launcing Chrome Browser Instance
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Thread.sleep(5000);//Thread.sleep() causes the current thread to suspend execution for a specified period.

        //3.  Open Url using get() method
        // get method is a abstract method it is only declaration method not a defination method
        // get method is used under the webdriver interface but declaration under the chrome driver class

        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");

        // 4. Maximize the window
        // Thread is a class name
        // whenever name in itallic form it will be static format.
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // 5. Delete all the cookies
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

        // 6. Open Url using navigate() method
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");

        // 7. Refresh the page
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().refresh();

        // 8. Navigate to back
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().back();

        // 9. Navigate to forward
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.navigate().forward();

        // 10. Fetch the current URL
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

        // 11. Get Title of the web page
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        // 12. Close the browser
        driver.close();

        // This is all WEB DRIVER commands as well as WEB DRIVER ELEMENTS

    }

}
```

Comment: `Unresolved compilation problem` means that you are running your code even though it contains errors that prevent compiling it completely. Make sure that you fixed all errors shown in the _Problems_ view before running your code. Consider to use Maven for your dependencies.